# If Hadwiger's conjecture is true for $k$, then it is true for every $k' < k$

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

I want to prove that if Hadwiger's conjecture holds for a positive integer $k$, then it also holds for every $k' < k$. Hadwiger's conjecture states the following:

**If a graph $G$ does not contain $K_{t+1}$ as a minor, then $G$ is $t-$colourable.**

A minor of a graph $G$ is a graph one can obtain from $G$ by deleting vertices and edges, and contracting edges  (an edge contraction is an operation which removes an edge from a graph while simultaneously merging the two vertices that it previously joined).

The graph $K_t$ is the complete graph on $t$ vertices.

Finally, by $t-$colouring I mean a colouring of the vertices of $G$ with $t$ colours in such a way that no vertex has the same colour with any of its neighbours.

How would one go about proving the required statement? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Letting $H(t)$ be shorthand for Hadwiger's conjecture, it suffices to prove $H(t)$ implies $H(t-1)$.

Suppose $H(t)$. Let $G$ be a graph with no $K_{t}$ minor. Form $G'$ by adding a vertex to $G$ and connecting it to all of the other vertices. Show that $G'$ has no $K_{t+1}$ minor, and use the resulting $t$-coloring to find a $(t-1)$-coloring for $G$.